# Chrome Dev Tools: 3 Different Lengths of Main Thread Blocking Time for Same Pageload?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

Per Chrome Dev Tools, my total blocking time is 240ms. It is also 596ms. It is also 1212ms.

From Lighthouse:

[image]

Also from Lighthouse -- same report:

[image]

And from the Performance tab, same app, same home page, moments later:

[image]

I'm sure this makes sense somehow, but I haven't figured it out yet. Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 1):

Lighthouse may be grouping multiple different domains into a single classification of cloudfront.net.  CloudFront is a very common CDN for Third Parties to leverage.  For example the site may have thirdparty1.cloudfront.net and thirdparty2.cloudfront.net.  The second screen shot references thirdparty1 and the last screenshot references thirdparty2, potentially.  Therefore, you're seeing two completely different services in the screenshots.

As for the first screenshot, that is the initial time.  Its possible the main thread is tied up for 240ms and then frees up.  Once the thread is freed, it can be consumed again (screenshots 2 and 3).